# Spring Integration for TCP Socket Client using Dynamic Host and Port

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, tcpsocket

I have a working example of TCPSocketClient using Spring Integration with hard coded host name and the port.

How to modify this example to accept the `localhost` and the port `5877` to be passed dynamically?

i.e. Is it possible to call the exchange method like  `ExchangeService.exchange(hostname, port, request)` instead of `ExchangeService.exchange(request)`

If so how does those parameter be applied on to the `client` bean?

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow client() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(ApiGateway.class).handle(
            Tcp.outboundGateway(
                Tcp.netClient("localhost", 5877)
                .serializer(codec())
                .deserializer(codec())
            ).remoteTimeout(10000)
        )
        .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
        .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ByteArrayCrLfSerializer codec() {
        ByteArrayCrLfSerializer crLfSerializer = new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
        crLfSerializer.setMaxMessageSize(204800000);
        return crLfSerializer;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("client")
    public ExchangeService exchangeService(ApiGateway apiGateway) {
        return new ExchangeServiceImpl(apiGateway);
    }
}

public interface ApiGateway {
    String exchange(String out);
}

public interface ExchangeService {
    public String exchange(String request);
}

@Service
public class ExchangeServiceImpl implements ExchangeService {

    private ApiGateway apiGateway;
    @Autowired
    public ExchangeServiceImpl(ApiGateway apiGateway) {
        this.apiGateway=apiGateway;
    }

    @Override
    public String exchange(String request) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            response = apiGateway.exchange(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return response;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic processing you may consider to use a Dynamic Flows feature from Spring Integration Java DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#java-dsl-runtime-flows

So, whenever you receive a request with those parameters, you create an `IntegrationFlow` on the fly and register it with the `IntegrationFlowContext`. Frankly, we have exactly sample in the docs for your TCP use-case:

```
IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f
        .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(Tcp.netClient("localhost", this.server1.getPort())
                .serializer(TcpCodecs.crlf())
                .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader1())
                .id("client1"))
            .remoteTimeout(m -> 5000))
        .transform(Transformers.objectToString());

IntegrationFlowRegistration theFlow = this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();
```

Comment: I'm able to connect the api but, I have an issue in this approach. For the first call, I get the proper response. and while I send the second request I get the exception like `BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'client1' defined in the 'com.sakthi.springintegration.tcpclient.config.ExchangeServiceImpl$$Lambda$394/810619513#1' bean definition: Cannot register bean definition [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; ...`

Comment: You should consider to delete those dynamic flows after use or cache them by host/port for subsequent requests

Comment: I have a private method in my `ExchangeServiceImpl` which has the above snippet and will return the `theFlow` every time. Using this, I call `theFlow.getMessagingTemplate().convertSendAndReceive("foo", String.class)` for each request. Is my approach correct? i.e. I autowired the ExchangeServiceImpl and calling the exchange method which will perform this convertSendAndReceive. It is working  fine now.

Comment: Yep! That's OK. Or you can wrap that into the `@MessagingGateway` interface.

Comment: Hi Artem Bilan, I autowired this ExchangeServiceImpl in to a controller and sending 2 requests one by one. Getting the same exception. First request has got successful and the second request throws exception like `bean definition: Cannot register bean definition [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory]  defined in the  ExchangeServiceImpl$$Lambda$395/1233672433#1 for bean 'client1': There is already TcpNetClientConnectionFactory bound`. Could you please add full working snippet?

Comment: No, we don't code for people. As I said: or you have to use unique bean names and cache the whole dynamic flow per host/port or you have to remove the flow in the end of interaction with it.

Comment: How to remove the flow? Hope it will resolve my issue.

Comment: The `IntegrationFlowContext.remove()` or `IntegrationFlowRegistration.destroy()`